# Waterline one-to-many with arbitrary foreign keys

Tags: waterline

Is it possible to have a one sided one-to-many relationship between two models?

What I'm trying to achieve is a plugin architecture, where the core app server has a base set of models, but specific implementation for different clients can include custom data plugins.

So I have the notion of a core `Entity` (super-simplified):

`{
  identity: 'entity',
  attributes: {
    id: 'integer',
    type: 'string'
  }
}`

Ok, now I'm going to add a `Passport` plugin to store login credentials.

`{
  identity: 'passport',
  attributes: {
    id: 'integer',
    protocol: 'string',
    username: 'string',
    password: 'string',
    entity: {
      model: 'Entity'
    }
  }
}`

So far so good. Now I want to add a `User` plugin, where a `User` effectively extends `Entity`, but a `User` can have a number of passports. So this is what I tried first:

`{
  identity: 'user',
  attributes: {
    id: 'integer',
    name: 'string',
    email: 'string',
    entity: {
      model: 'Entity'
    },
    passports: {
      collection: 'Passport',
      via: 'entity'
    }
  }
}`

Now things come unstuck in Waterline (but it's a perfectly reasonable data model). Here's the error:

`Trying to associate a collection attribute to a model that doesn't have a Foreign Key. user is trying to reference a foreign key in passport`

The point of the exercise is that the `Entity` is a rather abstract concept, and things like `Passport` are supposed to add behaviour without having to specifically know what the concrete implementation (`User`) looks like. Because I want a plugin architecture, a `Passport` can't know about a `User` explicitly.

It would otherwise be quite an elegant solution. Is there any way to coax Waterline into doing what I want? Thanks.